Why Java Spring App get Memory leak when I use PSPDFKit then app crash
When I directly fetch documents without using PSPDFKit, Memory functions as expected. The Memory leak seems to be isolated to working with the PSPDFKit library. Rendering many pdf files can fill 2GB of Memory then my app crash. This leads me to believe there is an issue with how I'm interacting with PSPDFKit that's causing the leak.
public byte[] annotate(byte[] doc) throws Exception {

        ByteArrayProvider pdfProvider = new ByteArrayProvider(doc);
        PdfDocument document = PdfDocument.open(pdfProvider);

        document.saveAs(inMemoryDataProvider,
        new DocumentSaveOptions.Builder().flattenAnnotations(true).forceSave(true).build());

        byte[] pdf = inMemoryDataProvider.read(inMemoryDataProvider.getSize(), 0);

        pdfProvider.release();
        inMemoryDataProvider.release();
        pdfProvider = null;

        return pdf;
 }

public class ByteArrayProvider extends InputStreamDataProvider implements WritableDataProvider {
  private List<Byte> pdfData = new ArrayList<>();

  ByteArrayProvider(@NotNull final byte[] data) {
    this.release();
    for (byte value : data) {
      pdfData.add(value);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void release() {
    pdfData.clear();
  }
}

public class InMemoryDataProvider implements WritableDataProvider {
  private final List<Byte> pdfData = new ArrayList<>();

  @Override
  public void release() {
    pdfData.clear();
  }
}

I hope someone can help me.
Thank you in advance.

You might want to try creating a heap dump and analyzing it in a tool like Memory Analyzer. This could help you find what actually participates in the memory leak.

I'm not expert in debugging memory leak, but I used Profiler with IntelliJ and heap memory is just fine. However, when I run the app in Production it gets full. Thanks

I am assuming you can reproduce the memory leak just using the code you provided. You can try doing that and then create a heap dump of the reproducer.
